# computer language like arduino language for visualization or game development

Tags: c++, visualization

Is there a language similar to Arduino language (c++ language with fewer functions) for software visualization?

Answer (score 4):

[Processing](http://processing.org/) is probably exactly what you want.

Comment: Ah good catch.  Processing is indeed an awesome language and development environment.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).  It's a lightweight scripting language.

Here's an article about game development using it...

http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-lua/

Comment: Lua have Polycode polycode.org , but seems there is no development GUI for windows like Processing?

Answer (score 1):

You should also look into [Scratch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_%28programming_language%29). It is educational programming language 
to create games. The good thing is you'll find many open source [projects](http://scratch.mit.edu/channel/featured) in Scratch to study.